# JSP Multiply Input and Variable and Show Answer in a Field

Tags: javascript, jsp, getelementbyid, multiplication

I'm working on a payroll type `JSP page` using `Netbeans 8.0`/`Glassfish 4.0`/`Firefox 49.0.2`. I'm generating a table with a loop which includes an input box and a span for each record in the DB, with IDs of “hours1”, “hours2”, etc, and “mixed1”, “mixed2”, etc. I want to take the value **keyed into** one of the "hours" inputs, multiply it by a variable (loaded from the DB, eg equal to 10), and display the answer in the associated "mixed" field. I've looked at a lot of other `StackOverflow` posts (& elsewhere), but something (usually the ID names) is getting in the way.

I can display the hours typed (into the hours input) into the span field just fine (see code snippet below), but when I try to do multiplication, it breaks. I've tried parseFloat on the value, I've tried saving that value to a variable followed by the multiplication and `innerHTML` assignment, and I've tried putting it into a `Javascript` function, but once I add the "* minWage" I get nothing.

I have similar things I want to do with other input fields, and this seems like it ought to be easy, but I just am not seeing it. AHWBA. Thanks -Bob

---

```
float minWage =10;

<td><input type="text" name="hours" id='<%= "hours" + k %>' 
oninput="document.getElementById('<%= "mixed"+ k %>').innerHTML 
       = document.getElementById('<%="hours" + k %>').value;"></td>
                 //would like above * minWage

<td><span name="mixed" id='<%= "mixed" + k %>' >/span></td>
--------------------------------------------------------
update:
        //this works
= (10 * document.getElementById('<%="hours" + k %>').value);">
        //but this doesn't (this is what I want)
= (minWage * document.getElementById('<%="hours" + k %>').value);">
```

Answer (score 0):

I said it ought to be easy, and it was. Since the variable minWage was declared in Java code, using <% ... %>, it had to be used through Java code.

This is what worked.

```
(<%=minWage%> * document.getElementById('<%="hours" + k %>').value)
```

Though this request for help had a few hits during the 5 days it was open, nobody had an answer. Thank you anyway. -Bob